# While loop wont stop in simple python number guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, numbers

Here is my function

```
# guess the number you chooses
def number_guess_you():
    import random
    bound = int(input('What is your number between? 1 - ?  '))
    valid_bound = isinstance(bound, int) and bound>1
    while valid_bound==False:
        bound = int(input('''
        \nPLEASE SELECT AN INTEGER GREATER THAN 1
        \rWhat is your number between? 1 - ?  '''))
        valid_bound = isinstance(bound, int) and bound>1
    low = 1
    high = bound
    feedback = ' '
    while feedback != 'c':
        if low != high:
            guess = random.randint(low, high)
        else: 
            guess = low
        feedback = input(f' Is {guess} too high (1) too low (L) or correct (C)? ')
        if feedback == 'h':
            high = guess - 1
        elif feedback == 'l':
            low = guess + 1
    print(f'Yay, computer guessed your number, {guess}, correctly!')
```

the while loop is the problem, any input i do, it keeps looping and the high and low values stay unchanged.

I was expecting to reset the high and low values after knowing more and exiting when the guess is correct.

Comment: I just pasted your code into my python and I had no problem with the loop exiting when I typed 'c'. Is your CAPS LOCK key on by chance? You're only checking for lower-case 'c' not upper-case 'C'

Comment: can you explain more about the problem?

Comment: I was using lower case letter. Im trying to make it so the user could enter upper or lower letters and for it to give the same result

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
# guess the number you chooses
def number_guess_you():
    
    import random
    bound = int(input('What is your number between? 1 - ?  '))
    valid_bound = isinstance(bound, int) and bound>1
    while valid_bound==False:
        bound = int(input('''
        \nPLEASE SELECT AN INTEGER GREATER THAN 1
        \rWhat is your number between? 1 - ?  '''))
        valid_bound = isinstance(bound, int) and bound>1
    low = 1
    high = bound
    feedback = ' '
    while feedback.lower() != 'c':
        try:
            if low != high:
                guess = random.randint(low, high)
            else: 
                guess = low
            feedback = input(f' Is {guess} too high (H) too low (L) or correct (C)? ')
            if feedback.lower() == 'h':
                high = guess - 1
            elif feedback.lower() == 'l':
                low = guess + 1
        except Exception as e:
            print("Critical error found!!")
    print(f'Yay, computer guessed your number, {guess}, correctly!')
    
number_guess_you()
```

I have done some modifications into it. Hope this helps!! ^_^